# Can't see the User on the login screen

Tags: macos, user-account, login-screen

My user name does not appear on the login screen. There are two users and only one is shown.

Is there any way to see the other user or some user name input box instead of selection?

Comment: If you log in with the only user shown, and then log out again (just log out, no restart), do you then see both users?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Press the Down arrow on the keyboard to highlight any user (make sure the password entry box is NOT open.)

Press Option + Return on the keyboard.

This should bring up the username and password fields on the login screen.

Comment: You saved me!
I had just wiped MDM profiles using the `profilesAreInstalled` method: https://graffino.com/til/UmkCdmEx7v-remove-a-non-removable-mdm-profile-from-macos-without-a-complete-wipe
And then enabled my "guest" along with a "standard" user. Something about non-admin users caused my next restart to only show "Guest User".
I thought I needed to go down the path of deleting my `AppleSetupDone` per: https://osxdaily.com/2022/03/25/no-admin-account-mac-fix-macos/
But I think `opt + return` was all I ever needed to do!

Answer (score 4):

If you have FileVault enabled this can also be due to the fact that the user has not being enabled to unlock the disk.

This can be sorted out by going to the **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > FileVault** and if you see "Some users are not able to unlock the disk" then click on the **Enable Users..** button and enable the users you want:

[image: Screenshot of the Security & Privacy preferences pane with the FireVault tab selected and a message at the bottom of the window saying 'Some users are not able to unlock the disk.' next to a button to 'Enable Users...']

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** (from the comment "How can I change when I am not able to login")

If you can't login with the only user available on the interface, I presume you don't know the password?

If so, you may try the following to set a new one:

1. Reboot in single user mode (press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> while rebooting)
2. type `ls -l /Users` to list your user accounts

Then, with replacing `username` and `new_password` accordingly:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
dscl . -passwd /Users/username new_password
exit
```

---

Or, another option, if you have a MacOS install disk:

Start with your install disk (reboot with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, go to Terminal from the top menu, and type `resetpassword`.

---

**Original answer**

1. Go to "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups"
2. Click on the Lock at the bottom left (to unlock changes).
3. Click "Login Options"
4. Select "Name and password" instead of "List of users"

[image]

---

However, if you can't login with "List of users", chances are you won't be able to login with "Name and password" option either.

You may check your user accounts on that same panel for examination.

Comment: How can I change when I am not able to login.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Ok I didn't get that. I updated my answer.